# I'm using the Kadence theme and I want to replace the product page with the one created in Elementor

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, elementor

I'm using the Kadence theme, in that ecommerce modality that it makes available for free, but the default product page I find strange, so I created a Template in Elementor and chose the Product Page option, THEORETICAL this would already replace the default product page, but to my surprise, the original page of the theme continued, which as I said I find it strange, how would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

In the single product template you need to set **display conditions** for the template - please look at below image for more detail:
[image]